# How to find particular index in icarousel ios?

Tags: ios, icarousel

i am using `iCarousel` with some items(equal to array count) having label  in it from  January to december.
What to do,If i have to find index of December  element and do auto scroll to that particular index.

For auto scrolling i have found 1 method

`[_carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:(NSInteger*) animated:(BOOL)];`

How to find index of item having December label?Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the index of the object in your array and it will match the index of the view in the carousel. If your array contains strings then you can get the index of december by saying

```
 NSInteger index = [array indexOfObject:@"December"];
```